# Merge two forms codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to codeigniter and I am currently working on a register form. For the moment I just want the user to input their first name and a picture. However, I have 2 different controllers to handle this and I have no clue of how to merge them into a single form without having two different submit buttons.

**View**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <section class="page col-md-8">

        <h2 class="page-title">Registration Form</h2>


        <form method="post" id="expertiseForm" action="" >

        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>

            <?php $attributes = array("name" => "expertiseform");
            echo form_open("index.php/expertise/index", $attributes);?>

              <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name&#160;</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('fname'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></span>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"> 
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="form-submit'">Submit</button>
              </div>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </form>


        <!-- Upload form -->
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('index.php/upload/do_upload', array('id' => 'uploadForm'));?>

          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="control-label" for="filephotograph">Photograph:&#160;</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="filephotograph" name="filephotograph" aria-describedby="fileHelp" value="<?php echo set_value('filephotograph'); ?>">
            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Upload a photograph smaller than 2 MB in size.</small>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('filephotograph'); ?></span>
          </div>

            <input type="submit" value="upload" />

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller for first name**

```
<?php
class Expertise extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('expertise_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/navbar');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[2]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        // fails
            $this->load->view('expertise_form');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        else {

            $data = array(
                'fname' => $this->input->post('fname')
                );

            if ($this->expertise_model->insert_expertise($data))
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You have successfully submit your expertise form for review.</div>');
                redirect('index.php/expertise/index');
            }
            else
            {
            // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error. Please review your information and try again.</div>');
                redirect('index.php/expertise/index');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**Controller for uploading photos**

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload()
        {

                $config['upload_path']          = './application/CAHSIfiles/uploads/photos';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filephotograph'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        redirect('index.php/expertise/index');
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        redirect('index.php/expertise/index');
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have one set of form tags with the url putting to one function that process your first set of form items and then does the actual upload logic

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('index.php/index.php/expertise/proccess_profile', array('id' => 'uploadForm'));?>

    <div class="form-group required">
       <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name&#160;</label>
       <input class="form-control" name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('fname'); ?>" />
       <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></span>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="filephotograph">Photograph:&#160;</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="filephotograph" name="filephotograph" aria-describedby="fileHelp" value="<?php echo set_value('filephotograph'); ?>">
        <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Upload a photograph smaller than 2 MB in size.</small>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('filephotograph'); ?></span>
      </div>

   <div class="form-group"> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="form-submit'">Submit</button>
   </div>



 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller

```
public function process_profile(){
    //logic from your upload controller and other controller here
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I took too long to give a reply, it took me a while to figure it out but I managed it. Thank you!